# getting error android.os.networkonmainthreadexception on login in an email account in onstartcommand() service method

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

Want to create a background android service that will continuously check the incoming emails. I have create an activity and there is an start and stop service button along with some input fields from user. On start service button click, I call the onStartCommand() service method and send the required details (email id, pwd etc) from activity to service via intent of service. Now, as I have to login in an email account in onStartCommand() I called Store.connect() method which is throwing an exception android.os.networkonmainthreadexception. I searched and found that I have to do the connect the email account tasks in Asynctask's doinbackground method so that main thread do not get disturbed. So, I did the same but even there I am getting the same error. But when I did the same thing in activity by making the async inner class then it is working fine but not in case of service.

Here is onstartcommand() method

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        String resp = null;


        if(intent !=null && intent.getExtras() != null){
            emailID = intent.getExtras().getString("email");
            pwd =  intent.getExtras().getString("pwd");
            urlServer = intent.getExtras().getString("urlServer");
            from_whom = intent.getExtras().getString("from_whom");

            AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
            //runner.execute(emailID, pwd, urlServer);
            resp = runner.doInBackground(emailID, pwd, urlServer);
        }
        if ((resp.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")))
        {
            startTimer();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



        return START_STICKY;
```

and private inner asynctask class

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String resp;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                //emailManager = new EmailManager(params[0], params[1], params[2], "smtp.gmail.com", "imap.gmail.com");
                emailManager = new EmailManager("test2891test", "Testing2891!", "gmail.com", "smtp.gmail.com", "imap.gmail.com");
                Message[] emails = emailManager.getMails();
                Message latest_email = emails[emails.length -1]; // latest email
                email_from = InternetAddress.toString(latest_email.getFrom());
                email_sub = latest_email.getSubject();

                Multipart mp = (Multipart) latest_email.getContent();
```

getting error android.os.networkonmainthreadexception in emailmanager.getmails() method for store.connect():

```
public Message[] getMails() throws MessagingException {
        store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(mailServer, account.emailAddress, account.password);
        inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();

        return result;
    }
```

IF I WILL DO ALL THESE ASYNCTASK IN ACTIVITY THEN IT IS WORKING FINE BUT RAISING THE ERROR IN CASE OF SERVICE.

ANY HELP WOULD BE WELL APPRECIATED.

THANKS

Comment: You are not using AsyncTask correctly and it does not run in background. Please read basic [AsyncTask tutorial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: Dalija  Thanks for your reply, but I am not getting where I am making the mistake. I had already read the tutorial link shared by you, and I implemented the same async task on activity where it is working fine but in case of service it showing the said error. It would be nice if you can elaborate further, or without asyntask how can I open the store.connect() function.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the asyntask in wrongful manner that is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22440804/7361890 now I have come over the main thread error.